# Error al recoger datos de DatagridView

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagrid

Buenos días compañer@s.

Os pongo en situación.
Tengo, en un formulario hecho en vb un DatagridView que relleno a partir de una consulta sobre una base de datos, hasta ahí todo bien.

Este es el Grid:
[image: Grid]

Cuando marco los Check que quiero tengo 2 formas de guardar, pulsando el botón donde pone Guardar o pulsando el botón pequeñito que hay arriba a la izquierda. El primero es un Button y el segundo un ToolStripButton dentro de un ToolStripMenú.

Si pulso el botón guardar, recoge bien todos los checkbox pulsados y realiza la inserción en mi base de datos.
Si pulso el botón pequeñito, no me recoge el último check que he pulsado sea en la línea que sea, con lo cual no me genera el resultado esperado.

Y el gran misterio, ¡el código de ambos botones es el mismo exáctamente!

Así recojo los valores de los checkbox del grid:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grdItems.Rows
        
        Dim bool1 As Boolean
        Dim bool2 As Boolean
        Dim bool3 As Boolean
        Dim bool4 As Boolean
        Dim bool5 As Boolean

        bool1 = Boolean.Parse(row.Cells(4).Value.ToString)
        bool2 = Boolean.Parse(row.Cells(5).Value.ToString)
        bool3 = Boolean.Parse(row.Cells(6).Value.ToString)
        bool4 = Boolean.Parse(row.Cells(7).Value.ToString)
        bool5 = Boolean.Parse(row.Cells(8).Value.ToString)
        ...
Next
```

Como he dicho, ambos botones ejecutan exáctamente el mismo código y no doy porque se comportan diferente.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando editas una línea ésta pasa a estar en 'modo edición' (Edit mode).

El problema está en que al pulsar el `Button` externo 'Guardar', se termina la edición; sin embargo, al hacerlo desde el `ToolStripButton` no termina y sigue en modo edición, por lo que no tiene en cuenta los cambios realizados.

Si activas la barra izquierda de selección de las líneas verás que al pulsar el `Button` cambia a una flecha (indicando que ya ha finalizado de editarse y está seleccionada), mientras que con el `ToolStripButton` se mantiene con un lápiz 'en edición'.

Línea editada y que podrás recoger con tu código:
[image: Línea editada]

Línea en edición y que NO podrás recoger con tu código:
[image: Línea en edición]

Para obligarle a finalizar la edición añade:

```
grdItems.EndEdit()
```

Comment: Perfecto @AsieR_2, con esto lo he solucionado. Muchas gracias.